# What is the correlation between x and y?

Tags: complex-analysis, signal-processing

$x(t)=\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $t<0$ or $t>1$} \\
1-t, & \text{if $0<t<1$}
\end{cases}$

$y(t)=x(t-3)$

I am asked to find the correlation between x(t) and y(t). Here is what I have done:
[image: Here is what I have done:]

[image]

But in the reference they got to another answer, and I don't know what is the problem with mine:
[image]

[image]

[image]

They say that the correlation between x and itself is different from 0 between $-1\let\le1$ and because of simetry they can split the integral, but I don't understand why it is true or how they have got to these limits.

Thanks very much in advance to all the helpers!